# My program throws An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host exception

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, udp

I have written a little program that takes one udp address and sends the data to a tcp address instead. When i run the program in CMD and taking the two addresses i get an error.

Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IPEndPoint listening = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(args[0]));
    UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(listening);
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Listening on {listening}");

    var parts = args[1].Split(':');

    IPEndPoint newrelic = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(parts[0]), int.Parse(parts[1]));
    TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient();

    bool stop=false;
    Console.CancelKeyPress+=(object? sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) =>
    {
        stop = true;
        tcp.Dispose();
        udp.Close();
        udp.Dispose();
    };
    tcp.Connect(newrelic);
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Connected to {newrelic}");
    var dummy = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,0);
    while (!stop)
    {
       
            var bytes = udp.Receive(ref dummy);
            if (bytes.Length > 0)
            {
                if (bytes[0] != 0x02)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"Received {bytes.Length} bytes");
                    var sent = tcp.Client.Send(bytes);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The error i am getting is this: Unhandled exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\TcpToUdp\Program.cs:line 0

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

This error generally means that you need to implement TLS 1.2 in your code. Fortunately it's a one-liner that you need to add anywhere *before* your application attempts to reach the endpoint.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Hi! I tried adding this to some points of the code some times but i still get the exception...

Comment: Have you tried adding this as the first line in your Main method? Alternatively it might be a firewall-related issue, which is a little trickier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I do think that this could be a firewall issue in which i will have to look more in depth at. Tried the TLS implementation and got the same exception still.